# Spring Integration : Remove Jms and Http Headers from Message

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have a integration flow like this

**Subscriber & Publisher**

```
Broker->queue1->Transform->HTTP CALL->HTTP Response->JMS Message->Broker->queue2
```

This my integration flow DSL

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow orchestrationFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(connectionFactory).destination("MAILBOX"))
            //destination("amq.outbound1"))
            .<String, String>transform(s -> {
                return s.toLowerCase();
            }).log()
            .transform(new PojoTransformer())
            //.headerFilter("^(jms?|JMS)://.*$", true)
            .log()
            // HTTP part goes here
            .<String, HttpEntity<String>>transform(HttpEntity::new).handle(

                    Http.outboundGateway("http://localhost:8080/uppsercase").httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                            .extractPayload(true).expectedResponseType(String.class))
            .log()
            .headerFilter("(.*?)", true)
            .log()
            //.<HttpEntity<String>,String>transform(HttpEntity<String>::getBody)
            // and here HTTP part ends
            .handle(Jms.outboundAdapter(connectionFactory).destination("MAILBOXX")).get();
}

public static class PojoTransformer {

    @Transformer
    public String transform(@Payload String email, @Headers MessageHeaders headers) {
        return  email;
    }

}
```

I want remove Jms Headers from the message before making http call
Also want to remove the HTTP headers before sending it to JMS

I tried to different approaches using  `@Transformer`  and  `headerFilter`

But nothing work, 
Since clearing of headers is not happening  , unwanted headers are send to JMS and HTTP requests

I pasting the logs here

```
 GenericMessage [payload=something, headers={JMS_IBM_Character_Set=UTF-8, JMS_IBM_MsgType=8, jms_destination=queue:///MAILBOX, JMSXUserID=admin       , JMS_IBM_Encoding=273, priority=4, jms_timestamp=1532706892455, JMSXAppID=SpringIntegrationDemoApplica, JMS_IBM_PutApplType=28, JMS_IBM_Format=MQSTR   , jms_redelivered=false, JMS_IBM_PutDate=20180727, JMSXDeliveryCount=1, JMS_IBM_PutTime=15545246, id=5f5fe393-42e3-9ab9-3170-739bf7e4f72b, jms_messageId=ID:414d5120514d31202020202020202020872a5b5b02781521, timestamp=1532706892732}]
 GenericMessage [payload=something, headers={JMS_IBM_Character_Set=UTF-8, JMS_IBM_MsgType=8, jms_destination=queue:///MAILBOX, JMSXUserID=admin       , JMS_IBM_Encoding=273, priority=4, jms_timestamp=1532706892455, JMSXAppID=SpringIntegrationDemoApplica, JMS_IBM_PutApplType=28, JMS_IBM_Format=MQSTR   , jms_redelivered=false, JMS_IBM_PutDate=20180727, JMSXDeliveryCount=1, JMS_IBM_PutTime=15545246, id=d81f301b-7033-65be-9dd2-6bda3a200b3a, jms_messageId=ID:414d5120514d31202020202020202020872a5b5b02781521, timestamp=1532706892737}]
 GenericMessage [payload=SOMETHING IS CONVERTED TO UPPERCASE, headers={JMS_IBM_Character_Set=UTF-8, JMS_IBM_MsgType=8, jms_destination=queue:///MAILBOX, JMSXUserID=admin       , JMS_IBM_Encoding=273, priority=4, jms_timestamp=1532706892455, http_statusCode=201, Date=1532706892000, JMSXAppID=SpringIntegrationDemoApplica, JMS_IBM_PutApplType=28, JMS_IBM_Format=MQSTR   , jms_redelivered=false, JMS_IBM_PutDate=20180727, JMSXDeliveryCount=1, JMS_IBM_PutTime=15545246, id=e464d287-b32b-0bdc-e008-c3d5bf70e45a, Content-Length=35, contentType=text/plain;charset=UTF-8, jms_messageId=ID:414d5120514d31202020202020202020872a5b5b02781521, timestamp=1532706892783}]
 GenericMessage [payload=SOMETHING IS CONVERTED TO UPPERCASE, headers={JMS_IBM_Character_Set=UTF-8, JMS_IBM_MsgType=8, jms_destination=queue:///MAILBOX, JMSXUserID=admin       , JMS_IBM_Encoding=273, priority=4, jms_timestamp=1532706892455, http_statusCode=201, Date=1532706892000, JMSXAppID=SpringIntegrationDemoApplica, JMS_IBM_PutApplType=28, JMS_IBM_Format=MQSTR   , jms_redelivered=false, JMS_IBM_PutDate=20180727, JMSXDeliveryCount=1, JMS_IBM_PutTime=15545246, id=e464d287-b32b-0bdc-e008-c3d5bf70e45a, Content-Length=35, contentType=text/plain;charset=UTF-8, jms_messageId=ID:414d5120514d31202020202020202020872a5b5b02781521, timestamp=1532706892783}]
: failed to map Message header 'Content-Length' to JMS property
```

could somebody tell me why my transformations is not working properly

Comment: Have you tried <int:header-filter input-channel="headerFilterChannel"
        header-names="original-payload" output-channel="responseOutChannel" /> ?

Comment: @RamandeepKaur could you please post DSL equivalent of this??

Answer (score 1):

You really need to use a `.headerFilter()`, but only the problem that it doesn't support `regexp`:

```
/**
     * Removes all headers provided via array of 'headerPatterns'. As the name suggests the array
     * may contain simple matching patterns for header names. Supported pattern styles are:
     * "xxx*", "*xxx", "*xxx*" and "xxx*yyy".
     *
     * @param headerPatterns The header patterns.
     * @return this.
     */
    public abstract AbstractIntegrationMessageBuilder<T> removeHeaders(String... headerPatterns);
```

Comment: thanks ,what id did was  headerFilter("*"), not sure is it the right way. Also it hing this situation it will work. but if the flow got another sub-flow think it will not